# Matching word pattern with character pattern

Tags: regex, algorithm

So I have a very interesting question where I have a long string **s** such as:

```
eatsleepeatwalksleepwalk
```

and a smaller string **p** such as:

```
esetst
```

so on a quick look you can deduce that:

```
eat = e
sleep = s
walk = t
```

The problem statement is to tell whether the pattern of **characters in smaller string p** matches the **words in the bigger string s**

```
Size of s = 0 to 1000
Size of p = 0 to 1000
```

I'm aware of simple pattern matching using KMP, however this problem seems quite tricky and I'm unable to get to a starting point of solving this problem.

Any hints?

**Edit 1:** Look at **@Neverever**'s answer below. Seems quite interesting, awaiting examination of space/time complexity.

Comment: You more or less need a brute force search here. That is, looking just at the first character of the smaller string, e could stand for e, ea, eat, eats, ... and you just try all these possibilities in order.

Comment: @n.m. your comment is helpful. However, I would prefer any efficient way of creating this map [words-char]. The brute force would make the run time to be O(n^2) or even worse which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: maximum length of s ?

Comment: @n.m. 'e' could also map to a word not starting with 'e', in the example walk maps to 't'

Comment: @arenard um, yes, of course. but in this example, e maps to a word starting with e.

Comment: I don't think there's more efficient method. The regex solutions are nice but they just hide the complexity in the regex engine. I believe it will still be the same complexity in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to solve it using JavaScript RegExp

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  let p      = $("#p").val()
    , s      = $("#s").val()
    , regMap = []
    , regStr = "";

  for (let c of p) {
    let idx = regMap.indexOf(c);

    if (idx === -1) {
      regMap.push(c);
      regStr += "(.+)";
    } else {
      regStr += "\\" + (idx + 1);
    }
  }
  let reg = new RegExp("^" + regStr + "$");
  console.log("RegExp used: " + regStr)
  console.log("Result: " + reg.test(s));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>String `s`: <input type="text" id="s" value="eatsleepeatwalksleepwalk" /></label><br>
<label>String `p`: <input type="text" id="p" value="esetst" /></label><br>

<button type="button">Run</button>
```

Comment: your solution complexity ?

Comment: I'm giving a +1 since your solution actually works. Will examine the space/time complexity before accepting this as an answer.

Comment: @arenard I can see no requirement that different letters must not map to identical substrings. If there's such a requirement, then a simple regex solution won't work.

Comment: @arenard I think you've mixed up with `p` & `s`, please try your example again, it worked for me (result is `false`).

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything I'm not an expert in evaluating RegExp complexity, sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: One upper bound of this algorithm is the number of string partitions of `s` with size `p.length`. Determining all string partitions is NP-complete.